# Can we load images to python from a directory without using PIL? What are other methods?

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I'm going to write a python script for loading images from a directory and resizing them, so when I'm loading images from a directory I tried these both methods;

Using PIL:

```
from os import listdir
from PIL import Image as PImage
import split_folders
import os, os.path
#imgs.append(Image.open(os.path.join(path,image))

def loadImages(path):
    imagesList = listdir(path)
    loadedImages = []
    for image in imagesList:
        with open(os.path.join(path, image), 'rb') as i:
            img = PImage.open(i)
            loadedImages.append(img)
    return loadedImages

path = "./Inputs/"
imgs = loadImages(path)

for img in imgs:
    print(img)
```

without using PIL:

```
import os

import numpy as np
import split_folders

def get_files_with_ext(path):
    file_list = []
    for file in os.listdir(path):
        file_path = os.path.join(path, file)  
        if file_path.endswith('png'):  
            file_list.append(file_path)
        if file_path.endswith('jpg'):  
            file_list.append(file_path)

    return file_list


imgs = get_files_with_ext("./Inputs")
for img in imgs:
    print(img)
```

Are both same?

Comment: Do the outputs look the same?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? You can resize all JPEG images in the current directory to be maximum 640x480 pixels with **ImageMagick** in the Terminal using `magick mogrify -resize 640x480 *.jpg` No code required.

Comment: I know about it @Mark, :) here I'm developing a project, need to write a script for that

Comment: Think carefully about making massive demands on memory by loading a large list of images at the same time - consider loading one at a time and processing it before loading the next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example, you create a list `loadedImages = []`, to which you append an `img`, the result of `PImage.open(i)`, which is an `Image` or `PImage` object, according to [the pillow documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html). In the second example, you create a `file_list`, which you then append a `file_path` to.

The first list contains opened (but as of yet unloaded) image objects. This object can be used to load & manipulate the images directly.

In the second snippet you have a list of strings that represent the filepath. These must first be loaded as image objects, before you can do anything else. However, this second approach could be used as a general-purpose method for aggregating paths to files of a specific type, that you can subsequently load and manipulate.

You do not **need** Pillow to open the file. You could just open().read() the file - but then you'll get a string that represents the image as a bytestream. What do you want to do with the files after loading them? If it involves image manipulation, then that justifies using Pillow to load the image.

Comment: Which one is better? @SambalMinion

Comment: Yes, Both, Neither. It's what you want to do next, that determines which one is better. After running these two snippets, you still only have a list of references to images.